# Firebase security rules operating fees

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've recently considering various security issues of my Firebase services and faced an interesting issue related to the Firebase pricing. The question is simple as below:

1. If a set of security rules of realtime database read some data inside itself(rtdb) within the security rules' validation process, are such server-reading for validating purpose subject to any part of rtdb billing? For example, if a line of rule needs a "role" data in the matching rtdb's json tree, is such validation free from rtdb pricing of download fee($1/GB) or connection quota(Simultaneous connections of 200,000)? It might be true because the validation must read the data anyway to find out if the request is compliant with the rules.
2. If a set of security rules of cloud firestore read some data inside itself(firestore) within the security rules' validations, are such data-reading for validation subject to read operation fee of firestore($0.036 per 100,000 documents in LA location)? For example, to validate a line `allow read if resource.data.visibility == 'public'`, the rule have to retrieve data just like a mobile client read such data without any security rule.

Hope this question reach gurus in the community! Thank you in advance [:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*firebaser here*

1. There is no charge for reads done inside **Realtime Database** security rules. They are also not counted as persistent connections.
2. Accessing the current `resource` or the future `request.resource` data in your **Firestore** security rules are **not** charged. Additional document reads (with `get()`, `getAfter()`, `exists()` and `existsAfter()`) that you perform  **are** charged.

For more on the latter, see the Firebase documentation on [access calls and pricing in Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_calls_and_pricing).

Comment: Thank you always for your answers, sir. I'm planning to leverage such price/quota advantages of security rules to defend ddos attempts. Learning from master!! [: